# How can I change the playback speed of my audio file using a module in python?

Tags: python, mp3, playback, pydub, slowdown

I have a project with multiple mp3 audio files and i would like to create a slow/speed button to change the playback speed of the song whilst it is playing, althought it would be fine if i could change it before the song is playing as well. audio quality is not that important. I just can't seem to find anything that works...

I tried using pydub to create a new mp3 file which is slowed down but it just got into a loop and didn't work. also i don't want a new mp3 file i just want to audio to be *played* in the background in a differnet playback speed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.